# What is the Chain object in OkHttp Interceptors? Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am watching a tutorial on how to add headers with OkHttp Interceptors, but I am confused about a few things.

- What is a `Chain` object?
- What does `Request original = chain.request()` do?
- What does `return chain.proceed(request)` do?

Code:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    // Request customization: add request headers
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); 

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
});

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

Comment: This simple-looking method is where all the HTTP work happens, producing a response to satisfy the request. If chain.proceed(request) is being called more than once previous response bodies must be closed.
Interceptors can be chained. Suppose you have both a compressing interceptor and a checksumming interceptor: you’ll need to decide whether data is compressed and then checksummed, or checksummed and then compressed. OkHttp uses lists to track interceptors, and interceptors are called in order.

Answer (score 9):

The Chain object in retrofit is an implementation of the [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern, and each interceptor is a processing object which acquires the result of the previous interceptor through `chain.request()`, applies its own logic on it (by a builder pattern), and usually passes it to the next unit (interceptor) using `chain.proceed`.

In some special cases, an interceptor may throw an exception to halt the normal flow of the chain and prevent the API from being called (e.g an Interceptor checking the expiry of JWT tokens), or return a Response without actually calling other chain items (caching is an example of this usage).

Obviously, interceptors are called in the order they've been added. The last unit of this chain connects to OkHttp and performs the HTTP request; then retrofit tries to convert the plain result taken from the API to your desired objects using the Converter Factories.

Comment: That's a real nice explanation

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    FormBody.Builder formbody=new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("ServiceId",ServiceId);
    RequestBody requestBody=formbody.build();
    Request Original=chain.request();
    Request.Builder builder=Original.newBuilder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .header("Authorization",Authorization);
    Request request=builder.build();

    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

Comment: While your code looks very cool we also like here to have a sentence or two to introduce it. Like maybe what you had to change to fix the original approach. I invite you to read this guide : "How I write a good answer" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer